# MySQL database repair

Tags: mysql, innodb, vbulletin

Using Vbulletin 4.2.0 PL3

I've used the repair / optimize database feature in vbulletin admin panel but these below tables remain at the same size. Is this normal?

Last column is "overhead" which always remain at those values even if I do a repair/optimize

```
searchcore      14.52 MB    34.08 MB    4.00 MB
searchgroup     3.52 MB     4.52 MB     4.00 MB
searchlog       5.02 MB     48.0 KB     22.00 MB
tagcontent      18.55 MB    34.58 MB    7.00 MB
```

The database is entirely MyISAM but these above tables are InnoDB. How can I safely convert them so I can proceed with the repair/optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert them to myisam you would run

```
ALTER TABLE searchcore ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE searchgroup ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE searchlog ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE tagcontent ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

That said, the overhead you're seeing is entirely normal with innodb. It allocates in chunks and so there will be overhead to the next chunk boundary. It's not a problem.